# Creating tuples of dynamic size in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, dynamic, initialization, tuples

Recently I was trying to create zipper for arrays. So for example: when user gives an input of 3 arrays of sizes: 3,5,12, the output array of tuples is the size of the largest array. And the output contains tuples of elements at given index, if there is no index, then there is null.

I tried the generic approach to make it even more useful.

So i created util static function:

```
public static zip<T>(arrays : T[][]) : () => [dynamic tuple here somehow of types T][] {
```

And i got stuck at the very begining, how can i define function that returns array of tuples of dynamic size ? Is it even possible? The typescript documentation is lacking such an example, so I guess my code will not work and i have to apply some workarounds, like returning any.

Comment: Could you be more specific out what result you want from the function? Why return a tuple with the elements of the largest array? Why not just returning the largest array? Do you want to provide the index as a parameter? Or is it the index from the array?

Comment: What I meant is that I want to transform list of arrays with some objects into array, of tuples. So in place of output array index 1, i want to have tuple of value [array1[1], ... , arrayN[1]]. And here is the problem, I dont know how to forge the returned type, or if it is even possible.

Comment: I have a picture, if it helps you @hanger : [link](http://i.imgur.com/x4uE5sK.png)

Comment: Thanks for the picture, but the picture just looks like an array of arrays? Do you also want each array in that array to have a name of some sort and that's where we need the tuple?

Comment: - those arrays inside array are actually tuples, at least i want them to be this way

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
class Demo {
    public static zip<T>(arrays: Array<Array<T>>): Array<[string, Array<T>]> {

        let max = Demo.getMaxArrayLength(arrays);
        let res: Array<[string, Array<T>]> = [];

        arrays.forEach(subArray => {
            for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                if (!res[i])
                    res[i] = [`Array${i}`, []];

                let value = subArray.length > i ? subArray[i] : null;
                res[i][1].push(value);
            }
        }); 

        return res;
    }

    private static getMaxArrayLength(arrays: Array<Array<any>>): number {

        let lengths: Array<number> = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
            lengths.push(arrays[i].length);

        return Math.max(...lengths);
    }
}
```